# Only printing values that meet a certain output criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, series

Pretty basic question I know but I'm new to python so here goes. I'm coding a program that "throws" 4 dice simultaneously and adds up their possible outcomes. Right now I have my code working entirely, but instead of it printing the count for every unique value I only want it to print the count for "18.0". i.e. 80 as below

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


four_dice = np.zeros([pow(6,4),5]) # 1296 rows x 5 columns
n = 0
outcomes = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
for i in outcomes:
    for j in outcomes:
        for k in outcomes:
            for l in outcomes:
                four_dice[n,:] = [i,j,k,l,i+j+k+l]
                n +=1
four_dice_df = pd.DataFrame(four_dice,columns=('1','2','3','4','Total'))
print(four_dice_df) # print the table of all possible outcomes
print(four_dice_df.Total.value_counts().sort_index()) # print unique values and how many times they each occur
```

**OUTPUT**

```
        1    2    3    4  Total
0     1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0    4.0
1     1.0  1.0  1.0  2.0    5.0
2     1.0  1.0  1.0  3.0    6.0
3     1.0  1.0  1.0  4.0    7.0
4     1.0  1.0  1.0  5.0    8.0
...   ...  ...  ...  ...    ...
1291  6.0  6.0  6.0  2.0   20.0
1292  6.0  6.0  6.0  3.0   21.0
1293  6.0  6.0  6.0  4.0   22.0
1294  6.0  6.0  6.0  5.0   23.0
1295  6.0  6.0  6.0  6.0   24.0

[1296 rows x 5 columns]

4.0       1
5.0       4
6.0      10
7.0      20
8.0      35
9.0      56
10.0     80
11.0    104
12.0    125
13.0    140
14.0    146
15.0    140
16.0    125
17.0    104
18.0     80 #only value I want printed
19.0     56
20.0     35
21.0     20
22.0     10
23.0      4
24.0      1
Name: Total, dtype: int64
```

So I've tried googling and looking at past questions on how to set criterias when printing and I couldn't find anything helpful but I am pretty certain the criteria for the output needs to be set somewhere in this line.

```
print(four_dice_df.Total.value_counts().sort_index())
```

Comment: `four_dice_df.Total.value_counts().reindex([18])`.

Answer (score 1):

You shoud create a subset of your data frame witch will only contain the rows where Total is equal to 18. You can do that with the following code :

```
dfTotal18 = four_dice_df[four_dice_df['Total'] == 18]
```

It will look like this:

[image]

Name: Total, Length: 80, dtype: float64

Then it's possible to count the rows with the function you already used, but you will no longer need the sort_index():

```
dfTotal18.Total.value_counts()
```

You can otherwise do it in one only step:

```
four_dice_df.Total[four_dice_df['Total'] == 18].value_counts()
```

You will end up with this result :

```
18.0    80
Name: Total, dtype: int64
```